# LibGdx : render Sprite and PolygonSprite on same batch?

Tags: libgdx, sprite, spritebatch

For my application, I need to render sprites (or textures) and PolygonSprites (or Mesh) in the same frame.
For the sprites, I render them on a Spritebatch, and for the PolygoneSprites, I should render them on a PolygonSpritebatch. But I really can't do that :

```
spriteBatch.begin()
spritebatch.draw(sprite)
...
spriteBatch.end()

polygonSpritebatch.begin()
polygonSpritebatch.draw(polygonSprite)
...
polygonSpritebatch.end()

spriteBatch.begin()
spritebatch.draw(sprite)
...
spriteBatch.end()

etc...
```

So, is there a way ?
Image is attached to see what i want.

[image: Sprite & PolygonSprite]

Thank's a lot !

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:**

You can use a `PolygonSpriteBatch` to draw a `Sprite` as well as a `PolygonSprite` like this:

```
polygonSpriteBatch.begin();

sprite.draw(polygonSpriteBatch);
polygonSprite.draw(polygonSpriteBatch);
```

**Longer Description:**

Drawing a `Sprite` or a `PolygonSprite` is done a bit different from the example code in your question. Since neither `SpriteBatch` has a method `draw(Sprite)` nor `PolygonSpriteBatch` has a method `draw(PolygonSprite)` you can't do `spriteBatch.draw(sprite)`.

The way to do this would be like this:

```
spriteBatch.begin();
sprite.draw(spriteBatch);

polygonSpriteBatch.begin();
polygonSprite.draw(polygonSpriteBatch);
```

Now since [PolygonSprite.draw](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/PolygonSprite.html#draw-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.PolygonSpriteBatch-) takes a `PolygonSpriteBatch` as a parameter, you won't be able to pass a `SpriteBatch` to this method.

But since [Sprite.draw](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#draw-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch-) takes a [Batch](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Batch.html) object as argument, you can pass either a `SpriteBatch` or a `PolygonSpriteBatch` as the parameter (since both of these classes implement the `Batch` interface).